# Error With Programmatically Segueing

Tags: ios, swift, button

I'm kind of new to Swift, and I was creating a program where I needed to use a segue through code. I made sure the identifier was correct, and I am in the right view controller. I tested to see if the button was the problem, and it wasn't. Here is the code and the error:

```
@IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        firstName = firstNameField.text!
        lastName = lastNameField.text!
        email = emailField.text!
        let contact = Contact(first: firstName, last: lastName, email: email)
        storageContacts.append(contact)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Done", sender: sender)

    }




override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationvc = segue.destination
        if let contactController = destinationvc as? ContactsTableViewController{
            if segue.identifier != nil{
                contactController.contacts = storageContacts
            }
        }
    }
```

Error(preparing, changed, pressed are print statements):

```
preparing
2016-12-09 15:07:23.337754 Contacts[11194:961012] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/nick/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7A8982FC-6CA4-4DB1-AA80-C58E83CDF7E0/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2016-12-09 15:07:23.339582 Contacts[11194:961012] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
changed
changed
changed
pressed
preparing
2016-12-09 15:07:29.354 Contacts[11194:961012] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Contacts.ContactTableViewCell 0x7fdf11820600> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fullName.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111ef734b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f20b21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111ef7299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010ed1b26f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010f79e80d -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 173
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010fae879e -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e9c590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010fae7122 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010f833df4 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 399
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010f8342ec -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 71
    10  Contacts                            0x000000010ec1b546 _TFC8Contacts27ContactsTableViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 150
    11  Contacts                            0x000000010ec1b7c7 _TToFC8Contacts27ContactsTableViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView12cellForRowAtV10Foundation9IndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 87
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010f8477b5 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 757
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010f847a13 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010f81b47d -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3295
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010f850d95 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 110
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010f8375ef -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 222
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010f79ef50 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1237
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114cadcc4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114ca1788 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114ca1606 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114c2f680 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 280
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114c5c767 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 475
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114c5d0d7 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 113
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e9be17 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e9bd87 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e80b9e __CFRunLoopRun + 1198
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111e80494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113daca6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010f6da964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    30  Contacts                            0x000000010ec20cdf main + 111
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112e2468d start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Copy and paste the error log from the debug console. Never post screenshots of text.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it.

Comment: the problem is in the error. "ContactCell does not have a property fullName". Somewhere you are trying to set "fullName" on something that doesn't have a "fullName". This crash is not related to the code you pasted.

Comment: In Storyboard: right click on the `ContactTableViewCell`. There is a refrenece set (IBOutlet) to `fullName`, which does not exist (anymore). Maybe deleted or renamed.